# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null geting error when amount change

Tags: javascript

i want to know why this error is occuring "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null" and where i am going wrong?
I am trying to add more functionality vut getting below error
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null" at increment_ppf_amnt (eval at globalEval (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2)

```
else if($action=='add')
        {
            for ($j = 0; $j <= $_POST['pro_ext_loc_count2_ppf']; $j++)
               { 
                    $str .='
                    <input type="hidden" name="ipsf_public_pf_id" value="<?php echo $ipsf_public_pf; ?>">
                        <table align="center" cellspacing="1" class="table table-bordered">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>PPF A/c No</td>
                                    <td>Account Holder</td>
                                    <td>Date of Payment</td>
                                    <td>Amount</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <input name="account_no_'.$j.'" type="text" id="account_no_'.$j.'" value="" size="20" maxlength="20"  class="form-control" onkeyup="Validate_number(this)"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="account_holder_'.$j.'" id="account_holder_'.$j.'" class="form-control">
                                            <option value="" selected>Account Holder</option>
                                            <option value="self">Self</option>
                                            <option value="spouse">Spouse</option>
                                            <option value="children">Children</option>
                                            <!--<option value="others">Others</option>-->
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input name="date_of_payment_date_'.$j.'" id="date_of_payment_date_'.$j.'" maxlength="2" style="width: 50px;" type="text" onClick="this.value="";" value="DD"  class="form-control-date" onkeyup="Validate_number(this)"/>-<input name="date_of_payment_month_'.$j.'" id="date_of_payment_month_'.$j.'" maxlength="2" style="width: 50px;" type="text" onClick="this.value="";" value="MM"  class="form-control-date" onkeyup="Validate_number(this)"/>-<input name="date_of_payment_year_'.$j.'" id="date_of_payment_year_'.$j.'" maxlength="4" style="width: 65px;" type="text" onClick="this.value="";" value="YYYY" class="form-control-date" onkeyup="Validate_number(this)"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>

                                    <input name="ppf_amt_'.$j.'" type="text" id="ppf_amt_'.$j.'"  value="" size="10"  onChange="javascript:increment_ppf_amnt(this.value, prev_ppf_amount_0);" maxlength="14" class="form-control-date" onkeyup="Validate_number(this)"/>
                                    
                                    <input type="hidden" name="prev_ppf_amount_'.$j.'" id="prev_ppf_amount_'.$j.'" value="0"/>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="is_added_0" id="is_added_0" value="no"/>
                                    
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                
                            </tbody>
                            <input type="hidden" name="total_ppf_amount" id="total_ppf_amount" value="0"/>
                        </table>';
                
                $k=  $j;
               }
                $str .='<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <div id="table_div_ppf_'.$k.'" style="margin:0;padding:0;"> </div>
                                    <div id="ext_loc_count2_ppf">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="pro_ext_loc_count2_ppf" id="pro_ext_loc_count2_ppf" value="'.$k.'"/></div>
                                    <div id="link_div_infra_ppf_'.$k.'" style="display:block">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="javascript:create_more_ppf_table('.$k.','.$k.');" class="link">[ + ] Click here to add more Details</a>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                </table>

                ';
        }
```

My add more functionality as follow:

```
function create_more_ppf_table(num_ppf,org_num_ppf) 
    {
            var add_ppf = num_ppf+1;
            var link_div_table_ppf = document.getElementById('link_div_ppf_'+num_ppf);
            var div_count_ppf = Number(document.getElementById('pro_ext_loc_count2_ppf').value) +1;
            document.getElementById('pro_ext_loc_count2_ppf').value = div_count_ppf;
            document.getElementById('ext_loc_count2_ppf').innerHTML = '<input type="hidden" name="pro_ext_loc_count2_ppf" id="pro_ext_loc_count2_ppf" value="'+div_count_ppf+'" />';
            document.getElementById('link_div_infra_ppf_0').style.display='none';
            //alert(num);
            var infra_table_div_ppf = document.getElementById('table_div_ppf_'+num_ppf);
            
            infra_table_div_ppf.innerHTML = '<table width="100%" cellspacing="1" class="table table-bordered"><tbody><tr><td>PPF A/c No</td><td>Account Holder</td><td>Date of Payment</td><td>Amount</td></tr><tr><td><input name="account_no_'+add_ppf+'" type="text" id="account_no_'+add_ppf+'" onChange="javascript:while(\'\'+this.value.charAt(0)==\' \')this.value=this.value.substring(1,this.value.length);" value="" maxlength="20" size="20" class="form-control" onkeyup="Validate_number(this)"/></td><td><select name="account_holder_'+add_ppf+'" id="account_holder_'+add_ppf+'" class="form-control"><option>Account Holder</option><option value="self">Self</option><option value="spouse">Spouse</option><option value="children">Children</option></select></td><td><input name="date_of_payment_date_'+add_ppf+'" id="date_of_payment_date_'+add_ppf+'" maxlength="2" style="width: 50px;" type="text" onClick="this.value=\'\';" value="DD" onChange="javascript:while(\'\'+this.value.charAt(0)==\' \')this.value=this.value.substring(1,this.value.length);" class="form-control-date" onkeyup="Validate_number(this)"/>-<input name="date_of_payment_month_'+add_ppf+'" id="date_of_payment_month_'+add_ppf+'" maxlength="2" style="width: 50px;" type="text" onClick="this.value=\'\';" value="MM" onChange="javascript:while(\'\'+this.value.charAt(0)==\' \')this.value=this.value.substring(1,this.value.length);" class="form-control-date" onkeyup="Validate_number(this)"/>-<input name="date_of_payment_year_'+add_ppf+'" id="date_of_payment_year_'+add_ppf+'" maxlength="4" style="width: 65px;" type="text" onClick="this.value=\'\';" value="YYYY" onChange="javascript:while(\'\'+this.value.charAt(0)==\' \')this.value=this.value.substring(1,this.value.length);" class="form-control-date" onkeyup="Validate_number(this)"/></td><td><input name="ppf_amt_'+add_ppf+'" type="text" id="ppf_amt_'+add_ppf+'" onChange="javascript:while(\'\'+this.value.charAt(0)==\' \')this.value=this.value.substring(1,this.value.length);" value="" size="10" onblur="javascript:increment_ppf_amnt(this.value, \'prev_ppf_amount_'+add_ppf+'\');" class="form-control-date" onkeyup="Validate_number(this)"/><input type="hidden" name="prev_ppf_amount_'+add_ppf+'" id="prev_ppf_amount_'+add_ppf+'" value="0" /><input type="hidden" name="is_added_'+add_ppf+'" id="is_added_'+add_ppf+'" value="no" /></td></tr><tr><td colspan="4"><div id="link_div_ppf_'+add_ppf+'"><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr><td align="left"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:create_more_ppf_table('+add_ppf+','+org_num_ppf+');" class="link">[ + ] Click here to add more Details</a></td><td align="right"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:delete_more_ppf_table('+add_ppf+','+org_num_ppf+');" class="link">[-] Click here to Remove Details</a></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr></tbody></table><div id="table_div_ppf_'+add_ppf+'"></div>';


            if(num_ppf > 0)
            {
                document.getElementById('link_div_ppf_'+num_ppf+'').style.display = 'none';
            }
    }
```

Amount increment on change as follows

```
function increment_ppf_amnt(amount,id)
{
    var amount = parseFloat(amount);
    alert(parseFloat(id));
    alert(amount);
    if(!isNaN(amount))
    {
        var prev_val = parseFloat(document.getElementById(id).value);
        var total_val = parseFloat(document.getElementById('total_ppf_amount').value);
        var tmp_val = 0;
        if(prev_val != amount)
        {
            tmp_val = total_val - prev_val;
            total_val = tmp_val + amount;
            document.getElementById('ppf_total_amount').value=total_val;
            document.getElementById('total_ppf_amount').value=total_val;
            document.getElementById(id).value=amount;
        }
    }
}
```

When i change first (0 place) amount change functionality that time above error will be show. I am not getting what is exact issue. Add working functionality working fine , Geeting issue only first row amount change.

Error like "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null" at increment_ppf_amnt (eval at globalEval (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2)

Anyone have any idea what is wrong then let me know.

Comment: You are trying to read the property `value` from something that is null. Obviously one of the `document.getElementById` calls is returning null.

Comment: one of the Id doesn't exist in document that's why you are getting this error `value` of null try to find out which `ID` does not exist.

Comment: Also why you are parsing ID Value here in  `increment_ppf_amount`  like in this statement   `alert(parseFloat(id));`

Comment: I am getting issue only for 0th index row. Add row functionality change working fine. I am not getting what is exact issue.